# Using XFP-10G (120 KM Range) on Juniper MX routers

Tags: juniper, sfp, juniper-mx, optics, optical

Hi everyone,

We recently installed a new 10G XFP optics module in Juniper MX router. As per the customer , XFP supported range is 120 KM and it is from some third party vendor named 'menara'.
Menara produces various SFP+/XFP which are compatible with Juniper/Cisco and Alcatel (This is what their documentation says). I personally havent seen the XFP physically by holding it in my hand.

[image]

However , there are some confusions regarding this XFP :-

1. When we run the command '**show chassis hardware**' , there is no such mentioning that its a **NON-JNPR** XFP. Based on this , can we say confidently that it must be XFP from Juniper side?
2. If the above condition is not true , is it still possible for a XFP (which as per vendor is fully compatible with Juniper / Cisco) to **not be shown as **NON-JNPR** XFP in show chassis hardware**
3. Juniper itself makes XFPs for various ranges (SR,LR,ER and ZR). The range of ZR is 80 KM as per Juniper documentation. In our case when we are using 10G XFP 120 KM , it is still shown as ZR. Is it normal on Juniper routers that using XFP with range (greater than or equal to 80 KM
   ), XFP will still be shown as ZR in 'show chassis hardware' output . Are the codes of 80 KM and 120 KM same (ZR)?
4. What should be expected code in case ZR is only reserved for 80 KM?

**Below is the snapshot for brevity**

```
user@KMM-KMM-Edg-MX24-1-re0> show chassis hardware 
Hardware inventory:
Item             Version  Part number  Serial number     Description
Chassis                                JN120023BAFC      MX240
Midplane         REV 07   760-021404   ACAW5374          MX240 Backplane
FPM Board        REV 05   760-021392   CAAH6323          Front Panel Display
PEM 0            Rev 05   740-027736   QCS1231T0NS       DC 2.4kW Power Entry Module
PEM 2            Rev 05   740-027736   QCS1231T0NR       DC 2.4kW Power Entry Module
Routing Engine 0 REV 17   740-013063   9012037476        RE-S-2000
Routing Engine 1 REV 17   740-013063   9012037221        RE-S-2000
CB 0             REV 14   710-021523   CAAT8248          MX SCB
CB 1             REV 14   710-021523   CAAN7120          MX SCB
FPC 1            REV 11   750-038490   CAAM2321          MPCE Type 1 3D Q
  CPU            REV 04   711-038484   CAAL9202          MPCE PMB 2G 
  MIC 0          REV 18   750-028380   YJ7204            3D 2x 10GE XFP
    PIC 0                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           1x 10GE XFP
      Xcvr 0              NON-JNPR     BP163202770028    UNKNOWN  
    PIC 1                 BUILTIN      BUILTIN           1x 10GE XFP
      Xcvr 0     REV 01   740-031832   T11C00194         XFP-10G-ZR  --- > This is the XFP in question
```

Comment: Juniper does not *make* optics. They provide a mechanism to "sign" validated optics. ('tho they don't actually check every optic, nor do they even necessarily even see each optic.) As such any "NON-JNPR" optic simply does not have the appropriate signature in the EEPROM. As for "120km", read the fine print for the exact power budget. Many will have somewhat higher TX power, but the real Magic(tm) is in their receive sensitivity.

Comment: @RickyBeam. Thanks Ricky for adding more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When we run the command 'show chassis hardware' , there is no such mentioning that its a NON-JNPR XFP. Based on this , can we say confidently that it must be XFP from Juniper side?

The thing you're looking for isn't the absence of `NON-JNPR` necessarily, but the presence of a valid Part Number, i.e. `740-031832`, which is valid.  So, unless someone reprogrammed the EEPROM to make it look real when it isn't, it's safe.

> Juniper itself makes XFPs for various ranges (SR,LR,ER and ZR). The range of ZR is 80 KM as per Juniper documentation. In our case when we are using 10G XFP 120 KM , it is still shown as ZR. Is it normal on Juniper routers that using XFP with range (greater than or equal to 80 KM ), XFP will still be shown as ZR in 'show chassis hardware' output . Are the codes of 80 KM and 120 KM same (ZR)?

Generally speaking ZR isn't industry standard and it's left up to the vendor/manufacturer (not always the same thing).  That particular optic is qualified for 80km reach based on OC192 specifications, generally speaking, that's under ideal conditions.  If you're actually sending the signal over 120km of fiber (remember fiber distance != geographical distance) then I would assume you have some kind of optical gear in the path that's helping it with the extra 40km.

> What should be expected code in case ZR is only reserved for 80 KM?

Again, vendors/manufacturers may use the term ZR liberally and say it could be 80km or more or come up with a new designation (i.e. ZR+).  In your case it means 80km, so it is correct here.

Comment: We are using 120 KM XFP for dark fibre connectivity between 2 x routers , out of which one is Juniper MX240. There is no DWDM transmission between them. Just fibre.

Comment: Is it possible to check reach in KM of an XFP using junos cli?

Comment: All "qualified" really means is that it was checked against a particular expectation, in this case 80km.  It's generally possible to go beyond what something is qualified for, it's just pretty crazy that it's by a factor of 50%.  Juniper will only officially support it up to 80km, the extra 40km is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, sometimes, it depends if all of the identifying information is programmed in.  "start shell pfe network fpc1", "show xfp list" (match the ID to the port number), "show xfp # identifier".  If the distance is there it'll be something like "Length SMF:             10 km"

Comment: FYI, it will only show what the XFP is _qualified_ for, not the actual transmission distance.  You need an OTDR for that.

Comment: One last thing. Am i right to think like this that the display of ZR in 'show chassis hardware' is what is hard coded in XFP itself (be it from any vendor) and Juniper just reads it from XFP and display it in show chassis hardware?

Comment: In some form or another, yeah it's based on what's coded there.